# Trying to livestream youtube through python

Tags: python, youtube, stream

I am trying to stream youtube through python bypassing the download part. However i am getting an error from my current solution.
The code is :

```
import pafy, vlc
url = str(raw_input())
video = pafy.new(str(url))
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url()
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()  
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

the error i get is :

```
  File "musicdownplay.py", line 5, in <module>
  playurl = best.url()
  TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

i have declared as a string so i cant find the error

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API](https://pythonhosted.org/pafy/), `video.getbest()` returns a `Stream` object.

And a `Stream` object has an **attribute** `Stream.url`, not a function `Stream.url()`.

From the docs:

> **Stream.url**
>
> The direct access URL of the stream. This can be used to stream the media in mplayer or vlc, or for downloading with wget or curl. To download directly, use the Stream.download() method.

TL;DR: Change `playurl = best.url()` to `playurl = best.url`

Comment: I tried this, however i get another error doing that which was that vlc has no attribute 'Instance'

Comment: Could be a couple reasons. Maybe your own module is named ``vlc.py``? Anyway, debugging your code line-by-line in the comments is a no-no. If this answer helped solving your *initial* question, please consider accepting and/or upvoting. If you have further questions, you should create a [new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)